# Issue with MvxPluginLoader

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I use MvvmCross and I have installed plugins via nuget packages on xamarin studio on mac os...

Everything works well but sometimes when I add a plugin I got this error and can't build my app anymore:

```
Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxLoaderPluginManager" reference from "MvvmCross.Platform, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" (MT2002) "
```

It could happens with any plugins...

The error concerns my iOS project. The pcl aren't touched by this issue.

Any idea on how to solve it ?

Comment: I'm confused by the question.  You say everything works but *sometimes* when first adding a plugin you have a transient compile error?

Comment: Yes, sometimes when I add a plugin (Mvvmcross plugin), I try to build and run but it failed

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the exact same error when adding the PictureChooser plugin and resolved it by upgrading my MVVMCross packages to newer versions.  Version 4.23 (and newer) of MVVMCross built successfully, but earlier versions would give me that same error.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your plugin is referencing an older version of MvvmCross.Platform then your pcl/ios project?